# Module-scope variable refuses to be overwritten by an async function. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, electron

The module-scope variable "output" refuses to be overwritten by the async function "retrieveTextWrapper", and I cannot figure out why. My objective is to output the text on StackOverFlow's homepage. retrieveTextWrapper successfully scrapes this information, but I can't seem to assign this content to the output variable. What am I doing wrong? How can I print the scraped information from the main() function?

Note: I am using electron version 3.0.4 because bypassing CORS is less of a pain on that version.

```
const {BrowserWindow, app} = require('electron')
output = "this should be overwritten by the retrieveTextWrapper method"

async function main(){
   navigate();
   win.openDevTools();
   await win.webContents.once('dom-ready',retrieveTextWrapper);
   console.log(output);
   //prints "this should be overwritten by the retrieveTextWrapper method"
}

function navigate() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({width:900,height:900});
  win.loadURL(`https://stackoverflow.com/`);
}

function retrieveText(){
  return `document.querySelector("*").innerText`;
}

async function retrieveTextWrapper(){
  output = await win.webContents.executeJavaScript(retrieveText().replace("*", "#content"));
}

app.on('ready',main)
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `win.webContents.once()` does not return a promise (since interfaces generally don't accept both callbacks and return a promise at the same time).  Therefore `await` doesn't wait for the asynchronous operation to complete.  Therefore, you're looking at output before its value has been reassigned.  `await` only does something useful when you `await` a promise that is connected to the asynchronous operation you're trying to wait for.

Comment: Agree with @jfriend00. Also try logging output inside of retrieveTextWrapper after invoking and awaiting win.webContents.executeJavascript to isolate the issue.

Comment: To confirm this timing issue, add a unique `console.log()` statement before and after the `await win.webContents.once('dom-ready',retrieveTextWrapper);` and inside of `retrieveTextWrapper` and then you can see the sequencing of these log messages.

Comment: @jfriend00 yep, everything changes as it should within retrieveTextWrapper function. And your explanation makes a lot of sense. However, is it possible to wait for the callback to finish (using some other syntax aside from `await`)? That way, I can use the updated value for other operations in the `main` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`win.webContents.once()` does not return a promise (since interfaces generally don't accept both callbacks and return a promise at the same time).

Therefore `await` doesn't wait for the asynchronous operation to complete. Therefore, you're looking at output before its value has been reassigned. `await` only does something useful when you `await` a promise that is connected to the asynchronous operation you're trying to wait for.

To confirm this timing issue, add a unique `console.log()` statement before and after the `await win.webContents.once('dom-ready',retrieveTextWrapper);` and inside of `retrieveTextWrapper` and then you can see the sequencing of these log messages.

> Yep, everything changes as it should within `retrieveTextWrapper` function. And your explanation makes a lot of sense. However, is it possible to wait for the callback to finish (using some other syntax aside from await)? That way, I can use the updated value for other operations in the main function?

You have a couple options.

You could "promisify" `win.webContents.once()` so you could then use `await` with it.

You could put the callback inline and put the rest of your code in `main` inside that callback (a classic way of dealing with asynchronous operations).

Here's an example of promisifying `win.webContents.once()`:

```
function waitForDomReady() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // may want to check if document already has dom-ready and resolve immediately
        win.webContents.once('dom-ready', resolve);
    });
}
```

And, you could then use it like this:

```
async function main(){
   navigate();
   win.openDevTools();
   await waitForDomReady();
   await retrieveTextWrapper();
   console.log(output);
}
```

This assumes that the code in `retrieveTextWrapper` that calls `win.webContents.executeJavaScript()` does actually return a promise when it's done.  If not, you have to promisify that too.

Comment: @guy444 - See the promisify example I added to my answer.